# Segmentation fault when calling a function returning a pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I'm getting a segfault when calling a function that returns a pointer in C++. What's the problem here? The function seems to be doing what it is supposed to, but when it is time to return then it runs into problems.

```
#include<iostream>
double * v_scalar_prod(double a, double *b, int n)
{
    double *res ;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        *(res+i) = a*b[i];
        std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << "res = " << *(res+i) << '\n';
    }
    return res;
}


int main()
{


    double y[3] = {3., 5.45, 2.};
    double *z = new double[3];

    z = v_scalar_prod(4., y, 3);

}
```

Output:

```
$ ./program
res = 12
res = 21.8
res = 8
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: `res` points to nothing.  You should allocate some memory for it.

Comment: You should use `std::vector` (or something like `std::valarray`, where it's just `va *= 4.;`).

Comment: You don't allocate memory for res. `double* res` only declares the pointer variable. In fact, you won't just want it to point to a valid `double`, but you even need an array here (and if it's really C++, why not do it the C++ way, as cris suggested?).

Comment: `*(res+i) = a*b[i];` What does this even mean? The `(value at res + i) = a * (the pointer at b[i])`?

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit, It fills `res` (as if it was an array) with the elements of `b` (as if it was an array) each multiplied by `a`. `res+i` is like `res[i]`, which is a `double`, same as `b[i]`.

Comment: I tried std:vector, but thought it was too cumbersome for just a few simple vector operations. I thought I could get away with just using pointers. I'm rethinking that... Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: @Physico, They introduce way too many problems. Resizing, remembering to call `delete`, remembering to use the right form of `delete`, handling any exceptions that get thrown before you would have called `delete`...

Comment: @chris, so, assuming they are both arrays (they're not), OP is multiplying some `double` with values of `pointer`s?

Comment: I'm curious about the downvotes I got. Have I violated any rules here? I'm new here. Is this not the forum for such questions?

Comment: `I tried std:vector, but thought it was too cumbersome for just a few simple vector operations`  And you went for "fools gold" by believing that using a mere pointer would be less cumbersome.

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit, No, both operands to the multiplication are `double` and the result is assigned to a `double`.

Comment: #include <iomanip> is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
typedef std::vector<double> DoubleArray;

DoubleArray v_scalar_prod(double a, double *b, int n)
{
   DoubleArray res(n);
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
   {
        res[i] = a*b[i];
        std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << "res = " << res[i] << '\n';
   }
   return res;
}

int main()
{
   double y[3] = {3., 5.45, 2.};
   DoubleArray z = v_scalar_prod(4., y, 3);
}
```

No memory leaks, no tracking if delete[] is called, etc.  Also, this version can be used in a larger, more complex program without worrying about memory leaks.

The only thing that is up for scrutiny is if `b` in the `v_scalar_prod` function is pointing to valid memory before and during the loop.  You could also make `b` a DoubleArray and pass it by const reference.  Then you can do the following:

```
DoubleArray v_scalar_prod(double a, const DoubleArray& b)
{
   DoubleArray res(b.size());
   for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) 
   {
        res[i] = a*b[i];
        std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << "res = " << res[i] << '\n';
   }
   return res;
}
```

Now you don't need the `n` argument, as a `vector` knows its size by calling `vector::size()`.

Comment: Even better, take `DoubleArray b` and do `for (auto &x : b) {x *= a; /*output*/} return b;` or the C++98 equivalent if you so desire.

Answer (score 1):

you allocate memory for `z` but you are not passing it to a function. also, the array you are trying to fill within a function has no memory allocated for it. therefore, even if there was no segfault, the pointer you are returning will point to some random address. change it to the following (that's one of the possible fixes):

```
#include<iostream>
double * v_scalar_prod(double a, double *b, int n)
{
    double *res  = new double[3];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        *(res+i) = a*b[i];
        std::cout  << "res = " << *(res+i) << '\n';
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    double y[3] = {3., 5.45, 2.};
    double *z ;

    z = v_scalar_prod(4., y, 3);
    delete [] z;
}
```

Comment: That may work in trivial programs, but once you need to do that in anything more complex or write a larger program that calls v_scalar_prod in multiple places, this would not be the recommended way to go about this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm aware of that now. I'll give the std::vector or std:valarray another try.

Comment: @Physico - I posted an answer showing vector usage.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I remember what I didn't like about std::vector. I can't just initialize it like a simple array.

Comment: I can't do, for intance:  DoubleArray y(3) = {1,2,3};

Comment: @Physico - You can with `C++11` using the initialization syntax.  `DoubleArray y = {1,2,3};`

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the array

```
double* res = new double[n];
```

Or whatever variation you'd like.

That way when you dereference the point here:

```
*(res+i) = a*b[i];
```

You can use the assign operator to assign the value at that space to the value you calculate.